# If statement with multiple actions in R

Tags: r

I would like to write an if statement of the following form:

```
a=5
b=2

la<-function(a,b){
if(a>3){a}
else{b}
}
```

Now what I would like to do is not only have one action in the if statement but two, for example:

```
if(a>3){a and c<<-1000}
```

In this case to return 'a' and also write 1000 in variable 'c'

My question is how to put in multiple actions after the if statement.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should use the semicolon

```
if(a>3){c<-1000;a}
```

The last statement is the return value.

EDIT This works for multiple statements, too. You can omit the semicolon if you use line breaks, as in

```
if(a>3) {
  c<-1000
  d<-1500
  a
} else {
  e <- 2000
  b
}
```

EDIT: this should work with `ifelse` too. You would have to keep in mind that you are operating on a vector, though. Here is an example:

```
x <- sample(10, 100, replace=TRUE)
ifelse(x>3, {y <- 100; y+x}, x)
```

This adds 100 only to those elements of x that are larger than 3.

Comment: does the same apply if I have three? say: c<-1000; d<-1500; a ?

Comment: Do note that this does not return c, d, and a when used in a function. Then only a is returned.

Comment: I was looking for the same solution for the ifelse() R function, how to passs multiple actions as second argument?