# using ifelse in r with multiple returns

Tags: r, if-statement

I was wondering how to set two or more results from a true ifelse statement.
For example, I would like to set `y = 2` and `t=3` if `x=2`.  I was thinking the code would look something like this:

```
x=2 
ifelse(x==2,y=2 & t=3, y=0 & t=0)
```

however this does not work.

Comment: Do you need this to be vecorised or is `x` a scalar?

Comment: You could do: `if(x==2) { y=2 ; t=3 } else { y=0 ; t=0 } `

Comment: typically, you make the assignment from the result/returned value of `ifelse`, not within the `ifelse` itself. If you need it multiple times, store the logical vector as an index and use it in each assignment

Answer (score 3):

You may use if-statement block:

```
if(x == 2){
    y = 2
    t = 3
}
else {
    y = 0
    t = 0
}
```

Alternatively, you can try:

```
ifelse(x == 2, {y = 2; t = 3;}, {y = 0; t = 0;})
```

Comment: The second option is not such a good idea since `ifelse` is usually used for vectors of length > 1 and in such cases, your kind of use will produce different results than one may expect from `ifelse`

Comment: @docendo discimus I agree.

Comment: @docendodiscimus perhaps you could elaborate. {} in the formulation above will always return a single value, so what is the risk here?

Answer (score 0):

As answered here: [If statement with multiple actions in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14100643/if-statement-with-multiple-actions-in-r), for the block IF statement, the ELSE should be on the same line as the previous curly bracket.

So, instead of

```
if(x ==2) {
    y = 2
    t = 3
}
else {
    y = 0
    t = 0
}
```

the format should be (the ELSE is on the same line as the previous curly bracket)

```
if(x ==2) {
    y = 2
    t = 3
} else {
    y = 0
    t = 0
}
```