# Multiple actions in IF ELSE statement

Tags: r

A sample data frame looks like this:

```
df = data.frame(a=1:5, b=11:15)
a  b
1 11
2 12
3 13
4 14
5 15
```

How do I use if else statement to create new column c and d in the data frame?
I want the output to look like this:

```
a b    c    d
1 11 'yes'  22
2 12 'yes'  24
3 13 'yes'  26
4 14 'no'   14
5 15 'no    15
```

I've tried this according to ([If statement with multiple actions in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14100643/if-statement-with-multiple-actions-in-r))!

```
for (i in nrow(df)){
  if (df$a[i] <4) {
    df$c[i] = 'yes'; 
    df$d[i] = df$b[i]*2;
    df
  } else {
    df$c[i] = 'no'; 
    df$d[i] = df$b[i];
    df
  }
}
```

But the output only provide the last row:

```
 a  b   c  d
 1 11 <NA> NA
 2 12 <NA> NA
 3 13 <NA> NA
 4 14 <NA> NA
 5 15   no 15
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your for loop should be: `for(i in 1:nrow(df))`

Comment: ahhh! i could i missed it. thanks!

Comment: A vectorized solution: `df[c("c", "d")] <- list(c("no", "yes")[(df$a < 4) + 1L], df$b * (1:2)[(df$a < 4) + 1L])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another vectorized solution using `ifelse()`:

```
df$c <- ifelse(df$a < 4, 'yes', 'no')
df$d <- ifelse(df$a < 4, df$b*2, df$b)
```